# Optimizing a Function that Returns "ON" Every Second

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, time

I'm very new to python, and I'm trying to make a sort of idle game. I'm having a little bit of trouble optimizing a function I wrote that flashes "ON" and then "OFF" every time a second passes.

While it works fine, it checks to see if a second has passed so many times that it peaks my CPU. The code is below:

```
import time
def timer():
  oldtime = int(time.time())
  #grabs the time on initiation
  while True:
    if oldtime < int(time.time()):
      return 'ON'
      #flashes on
      return 'OFF'
      #makes everything that checks if it's on only proc once
      oldtime += int(time.time()) - oldtime
      #makes oldtime advance one second ahead of time.time(),
      #even if more than one second passes at a time

timer()
while timer() == "ON":
  print('lorem ipsum')
#output: lorem ipsum every second and a peaking CPU
```

How would one go about optimizing something like this?

Comment: You don't seem to quite understand what `return` does.  Everything in your function after `return 'ON'` is unreachable and completely irrelevant; returning *ends the function*.

Comment: You _could_ use `yield` instead of `return`; put a sleep inside your timer function, and then `for value in timer(): if value == 'ON': ...` would be on the road to being meaningful/useful, though if you're not careful to adjust your sleep durations to compensate for differences between requested and actual delays (and time spent outside the sleep) you get drift.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have written a while loop that calls a function that will check the previous state of a variable and depending on whether it was ON or OFF it will sleep for 1 second and change to the other state.

```
import time
def repeat():
    isOn = True
    if(isOn):
       time.sleep(1)
       isOn = False
       return 'OFF'
    if(isOn != True):
       time.sleep(1)
       isOn = True
       return 'ON'
 while True:
 #You could always take the return value of repeat() to do something else 
 #in your code
     repeat()
```

Comment: Note that `time.sleep(1)` will cause the loop to run slightly _slower_ than once per second on average, because you're waiting a second without taking into account how much time was spent running non-sleep code, waiting for the operating system to context-switch the process back to foreground, etc.

Comment: (See folks talking about "drift" on the linked duplicate)

Comment: The other, bigger issue here is that `isOn` isn't static: every time your function starts it's always reset to `True`, so `if(isOn != True)` will never be run.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to make the variable static? I know in Java I need the static keyword But I didn't know they existed in python. From what I saw it looks like you need a class. Also when I ran it, I was able to print both answers.

Comment: A class is the _better_ way, but it's not the _only_ way; you can use a global, f/e.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is actually what you want as I feel like you are likely looking to do "something else" in the pause.

However, looking at your code, I think this will give you the result you are currently working towards. The key to not using up resources is to `sleep()`

```py
import time

def timer():
    time.sleep(1)
    return ["On ", "Off"][int(time.time() % 2)]

while True:
    print(timer(), end="\r", flush=True)
```